# How to Convert Date to Database timestamp format?

Tags: javascript

Good day, I am collecting data from different website using puppeteer, But the main problem is I am getting different kind of date format from different website like some website gives "6 days", some website gives "yesterday" some websites gives "15th August" like that. But I need to convert it to Timestamp format "2021-04-13T17:43:08.016+00:00" like that in javascript. Any Idea how can I do that? I have been googled but have not found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a library such as https://github.com/wanasit/chrono , this would parse human readable dates.